# Increase wifi signal in some part of the house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-adapter

In the living room the internet WIFI connection is very low and quite difficult to get sometimes.

I was thinking about buying something to solve this problem.

A friend of mine told me about buying a ["AV500 Nano Powerline Adapter Starter Kit
TL-PA411KIT"](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA411KIT) and to plug one close to the router and the other in the living room plug.

[image]

But of course, this one doesn't have WIFI. I would need to buy another router or another like this one but with WIFI.

Is this the way to do it? What would you do in my case? Does it makes sense this solution?
I really don't know much about networks and I'm kind of lost... I don't even know which other adapters also offer wifi... ([this one?](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1658&model=TL-WPA4220) plus one of the previous ones?)

Thanks in advance, any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your friend didn't spell out for you is that you should plug an Ethernet cable from a LAN port of your existing router into one of those powerline adaptors, and then plug another Ethernet cable into the other powerline adaptor in your living room. Then, when you needed an Internet connection in the living room, you could plug your laptop in to the free end of the Ethernet cable.

If you didn't want to be tethered to an Ethernet cable while in the living room, then you'd need a second Wi-Fi AP (you don't need a full router, just a simple "Access Point" device, if you can get one for cheaper than a full router), which you would hook up via Ethernet cable to the powerline adaptor in your living room.

Another possibility would be to buy a Wi-Fi repeater / range extender and place it somewhere in your house that's closer to the living room, but still close enough to your main Wi-Fi router to be able to join the existing Wi-Fi network. This wireless solution would be cheaper, but I don't like it as much because it ends up using wireless bandwidth for a data link between stationary devices, and I prefer to keep all my Wi-Fi bandwidth free for mobile devices. So I prefer to use some kind of wired connection between my main Wi-Fi home gateway router and my remote Wi-Fi AP. I prefer to run real Ethernet cable when it's feasible, but using powerline adaptors can work out fine when running Ethernet cable is too much work or hassle.

Comment: So, I should buy the  "AV500 Nano Powerline Adapter Starter Kit TL-PA411KIT" plus then an access point device to create the wifi connection in the living room. Could you recommend me any access point device for it? Thanks!

Comment: Any recommendation ?

Comment: Well, around mid-2013, nice reliable second-gen 802.11ac AP products started shipping. The Apple 2013 AirPort Extreme with 802.11ac is a very nice example. I recommend buying high-quality Wi-Fi gear because I hear too many frustrating stories here on SuperUser from people who buy cheap gear. I also recommend that when you buy new Wi-Fi gear, you buy state-of-the-art so it will last you longer, instead of buying stuff that can only do a half-decade-old flavor of 802.11 like 802.11n.

Comment: Looks quite expensive for me :) I'm abroad in a rented house and that's too much. I was thinking just for a cheaper solution. I'm not worried about having to replace it in 2 years :)

Comment: Which cheaper "access point" could I buy then? You were talking about getting a cheaper one rather than a full router but you never mentioned a cheap option, just the Apple one which is expensive. Thanks.

Comment: You'll be happier long term if you spend the money now. I just can't recommend cheap Wi-Fi gear, because it causes too many problems. I mentioned the possibility of a cheaper AP-only box, but I don't have any particular boxes to recommend.

Comment: Could you at least, orient me naming some brands who sells them? I can not buy an Airport Extreme if I might be leaving this house in 1 or 2 years... What is the name for this kind of products  "wireless adaptor"?

Comment: Ok, i belive this one for 15 pounds would do the work: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B006PYGWG6/ref=noref?ie=UTF8&psc=1&s=computers

Answer (score 1):

There are some such 'homeplugs' that have a wireless transmitter (not a range extender)...
I have one, which I havent used yet - at the non-router end, it has a wireless transmitter and an ethernet socket.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a router with multiple antennas, try to chenge their angles so that not every antanna points in the same direction.

Modern routers have a feature called antenna-diversity, so the router can pick the strongest signal from all of it's antennas providing a better coverage.

If you can change the antennas, the bigger the antenna the better the coverage

Comment: There's only one antena as far as I know, I will check it at home later and let u know. Anywya, the living room is downstairs and it seems there's something avoiding the signal to arrive, I even lose the 3G mobile phone connectin inside, so I guess this won't be a proper solution anyway.

Comment: One thing to be aware of ... the bigger the antenna, the more directional it usually is.  This could mean better coverage as long as it's oriented properly.  Oriented improperly, a directional antenna will attenuate the desired signal.

Comment: Could I get then a big antena instead of looking for other things?

Comment: bigger antenna or even directional antennas

Answer (score 0):

Before going on a buying spree, try to improve your current setup.

1. All transmit powers set to max or auto?
2. Adjust router/antenna positions to enhance coverage.
3. Select clearest Wi-Fi channel for use.

If you do want to buy something, depending on your physical setup, a better Access Point antenna may also help.

Comment: The living room is downstairs and it seems there's something avoiding the signal to arrive, I even lose the 3G mobile phone connection inside, so I guess this won't be a proper solution anyway.  I would rather prefer to buy something to make it work properly.

Comment: Well, you can't move the mobile cell tower, but you can move your own router, right?  Is there a metal 'reflector' shielding RF from your downstairs

Comment: I believe is both, the distance and the pilar of the house. I can not move the router, it is in a good position right now for the top of the house.