# What can I do to improve WiFi signal in remote parts of my home?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have really poor WiFi signal in my bedroom, which is on the second floor in the front of my elongated house.  I keep my WiFi router in the utility room, which is on the first floor, more to the back of the house.

I know for sure that the problem is in WiFi reception because when I bring the computer close to the router, the connection is really fast.  I am using a [300 Mbps Medialink N Broadband Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A3YN0Z0).

Answer (score 1):

You can either buy a WiFi repeater, which generally strengthens the signal of the router you already have. Or, you can buy another router, the best to be the same model/make, and set up a WDS http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System.

The last solution is to connect an Ethernet cable from router one to some second router, places on the 2nd floor.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check for sources of interference, personally I have had bad WiFi in the past because of materials the house was built from. Metal, concrete, plaster and some types of glass have potential for interference, that being said there is probably not a whole lot you can do about what your house is made out of, although it is something worth being aware of. Next up I'd check for electromagnetic interference (microwaves, security alarms, cameras, certain types of monitors, cordless phones and so on). If nothing seems to be working you may want to consider a WiFi repeater. Good Luck.

maybe [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/676264/increase-wifi-signal-in-some-part-of-the-house?rq=1) can help you?

or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/45960/which-methods-help-to-improve-wireless-signal?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Ubiquiti uniFi seems to be a very good product to do extense coverage of WiFi.

http://www.ubnt.com/unifi

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a WiFi extender like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E98O7GC).
Just plug it into an outlet in the room in which wireless signal is poor and set up to connect to your existing WiFi network.

another option would be using [powerline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AWRUICG).
these will transmit internet signal from one power outlet to another